# How to handle multiple AJAX behaviors in one HTTP request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance

I am using jQuery. I have implemented a multipart web page where a list of links* are rendered and each link is periodically updated through AJAX HTTP requests. That is, on the page there are many links of which each one is "timer-triggered" through JavaScript so to perform a HTTP request to the URL pointed by the link itself and, on response success, to replace those links with the retrieved data (the updated links).

This implementation works but it is "performance less" in cases when the page contains many links: one AJAX request is executed per link resulting in many hits to the server. In order to solve that performance issue I thought to make the JavaScript code to execute a unique AJAX request that retrieves the whole set of links and then to replace DOM data.

However I do not know how to implement the "unique request" mostly due to the practice/technique that I have to use and since it is the first time I notice this kind of problem. What can I do? Should I implement a JavaScript handler for event-registration or what?

---

* In my case link elements are used (`<a></a>` HTML tags) but those can be anything associated with a URL.

---

**Update** after the *jfriend00* answer

If the solution is to build a JSON array as *jfriend00* describes in his answer then I should implement the page behavior so to update the JSON array dynamically. Since my HTML links are even rendered dynamically along with some JavaScript code then that JavaScript code could update the JSON array dynamically by "registering"/"unregistering" links. If this is a solution in my case, how can I implement it?

I render links as "partial templates" along with the JavaScript code which JavaScript makes those links to execute AJAX requests. HTML-JS code per each link (the mentioned "partial templates") looks like the following:

```
<a href="xxx" id="link_1"></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var link = $('#link_1')
    ...
  }());
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you can just send some JSON that is your array of links to request and then receive JSON back that is an object where each key is the requested link and the data is the server response for that particular link.

If the links you want to process look something like this:

```
<a class="myLink" href="xxx"></a>
```

It could look something like this:

```
function processLinks()
    // assuming you can specify some CSS selector to select the links in your page that
    // you want to target
    // create an array of URLs for the ajax call
    // and an index of arrays --> DOM objects so we know which DOM object goes
    // with a given URL when processing the ajax results
    var urlArray = [];
    var urlIndex = {};
    var urlArray = $(".templateLink").each(function() {
        urlArray.push(this.href);
        urlIndex[this.href] = this;
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "your ajax url here",
        data: JSON.stringify(urlArray),
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(data) {
        // assumes you get data back as {"url1": data1, "url2": data2, ...}
        $.each(data, function(url, urlData) {
            // get DOM object that goes with this URL
            var domObj = urlIndex[url];
            // apply urlData to domObj here
        })
    });
}
```

---

Updating my answer now that you've disclosed your "partial templates".

To process them all at once, change this type of structure which processes them one at a time:

```
<a href="xxx" id="link_1"></a>
<script>
(function() {
  var link = $('#link_1')
  ...
}());
</script>


<a href="yyy" id="link_2></a>
<script>
(function() {
  var link = $('#link_2')
  ...
}());
</script>
```

to this which finds them all in the DOM and process them all at once:

```
<a href="xxx" class="templateLink"></a>
<a href="yyy" class="templateLink"></a>
<script>
    // process all the template links
    $(document).ready(processLinks);
</script>
```

Comment: I am newbie in JavaScript matters. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Could I build the JSON array *dynamically*? I mean, can I make a link to be registered someway in the JSON array when it is rendered on the page? Maybe, each link can be rendered together with some JavaScript code that dynamically register the link in to the JSON array... is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: @user502052 - Yes, the JSON array can be built dynamically from the content of a page via a CSS selector query.  See code added to my answer.

Comment: Maybe it could be implemented by using a global JavaScript array variable and when a link and the related "registerer" JavaScript are rendered then the "registerer" JavaScript can update the array according.

Comment: I updated the question since your proposed solution.

Comment: @user502052 - I can't think of any reason why you need to dynamically maintain a global array of links.  Just query them from the DOM when you need it.  Of course, you aren't disclosing your actual HTML or how you find the links in the page so I can't really help with that part.  If you want to maintain a global array of links (which does not seem required to me), then it's just a javascript array and you can use any of the javascript array methods to add, remove, find or change items in the array.

Comment: What have I to disclose in order to make the question clearest? I can provide more information, but what? I do *not* find the links in the page; instead I render links as "partial templates" along with the JavaScript code which JavaScript makes those links to execute AJAX requests.

Comment: @user502052 - What else do you want to know?  I proposed a solution where the first step was to build a list of links from with a selector query from the DOM.  If you get your links some other way, that's fine, but you've not told us anything about how you do that (I have no idea what a "partial template" is since it's not a standard HTML or JS thing) so I can't offer any more specifics on that.  You can build the initial array any way you want.

Comment: Sorry, as I wrote in the question "it is the first time I notice this kind of problem". For me, the issue is hard to explain but I tryed to update the question again in order to be even more clear.

Comment: @user502052 - OK, I added some more to the end of my answer.